# I need help modifying one of the examples to start a roScreen

Tags: roku, brightscript

In the example "Video List Markup" from the "Scene Graph XML Tutorial", when I select an item "itemSelected", I want to rewrite "playVideo" so it's creating a roScreen so I can draw my own images on it. Is it possible?

```
sub init()
  m.top.backgroundURI = "pkg:/images/rsgde_bg_hd.jpg"

  m.videolist = m.top.findNode("videoLabelList")
  m.videoinfo = m.top.findNode("infoLabel")
  m.videoposter = m.top.findNode("videoPoster") 
  m.video = m.top.findNode("exampleVideo")

  m.video.observeField("state", "controlvideoplay")

  m.readVideoContentTask = createObject("roSGNode", "ContentReader")
  m.readVideoContentTask.observeField("content", "showvideolist")
  m.readVideoContentTask.control = "RUN"   

  m.videolist.observeField("itemFocused", "setvideo")
  m.videolist.observeField("itemSelected", "playvideo")
end sub

Sub OnChangeXmlstringscene()
  m.readVideoContentTask.xmlstring = m.top.xmlstringscene
End Sub

sub showvideolist()
  m.videolist.content = m.readVideoContentTask.content
  m.videolist.setFocus(true)
end sub

sub setvideo()
  videocontent = m.videolist.content.getChild(m.videolist.itemFocused)
  m.videoposter.uri = videocontent.hdposterurl
  m.videoinfo.text = videocontent.description
  m.video.content = videocontent
end sub

sub playvideo()
  m.video.control = "play"
  m.video.visible = true
  m.video.setFocus(true)
end sub 

sub controlvideoplay()
  if (m.video.state = "finished") 
    m.video.control = "stop"
    m.videolist.setFocus(true)
    m.video.visible = false
  end if
end sub

function onKeyEvent(key as String, press as Boolean) as Boolean
  if press then
    if key = "back"
      if (m.video.state = "playing")
        m.video.control = "stop"
        m.videolist.setFocus(true)
        m.video.visible = false

        return true
      end if
    end if
  end if

  return false
end function
```

If it's not possible, how can I replace the video playing screen with a screen that allows me to draw my own jpg images on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`roScreen` and the other Roku SDK1 visual components as a rule are immiscible with the SDK2 (aka RSG, "scene graph") components.

So no, you can't (or don't you try) use roScreen when in RSG mode.

But you can do what you want by say adding a [Poster](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Poster) node to the scene.

Comment: @ioanghip - well, you either add Poster in the XML descriptor file for the scene in advance and later reach-around to get hold of it and make it visible or update the URL. or you can programmatically create/add node to the scene at runtime.

Comment: SDK2 is hard. Not on purpose but still. If you must use it, go through the tutorial, hopefully that will clarify some of it, https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Scene+Graph+XML+Tutorial

Comment: "If you must use it", is there an option? The only other option that I know of is working with screens... but how would I create the interface using screens if most of "the old stuff" is deprecated and as of July 1st 2017 Roku won't accept any channels using the stuff...

Comment: I figured out the Poster, but I'm stuck again. I'm building a mjpeg decoder and I need a fast loop for it. With roScreen works fine, but I don't see any way to do an event loop in a Scene

Comment: the rest covered in https://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=99336 ;-)